# How to display user fullname and save user id in SF form, without using select

Tags: php, symfony, autocomplete, symfony-forms

In a symfony project i have a Registration form in which, amongst other fields i have to display the selected User. The user is taken from the User entity.

**I need to save the user id (in the Registration Entity i save the UserId), but display the user fullname in the form field.
How can i manage that, WITHOUT a select field ?**

My conclusion would be to create a custom field with

- the name in a non form tag (span)
- the id in a hidden input

but in this case i dont know how to achieve it.

My User entity :

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
...
    public function __toString()
    {
        return ($this->lastName . " " . $this->firstName. " [".$this->getId()."]");
    }
}
```

My Registration entity :

```
class Registration
{
    /**
     * @var \MyBundle\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MyBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $user;
...
}
```

My first obvious attempt was to put the user field as an entity in the Registration form.

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('user', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => 'user.name',
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'reguser',
                ],
                'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\User',
            ]);
    }
}
```

I have a select with the user name displayed and id as value. The big problem with this is the ergonomy : i may have several thousands user. I can't display that big of a list.

So i thought about an autocomplete field instead.

```
    $builder
        ->add('user', TextType::class, [
            'label' => 'user.name',
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'reguser userpicker',
            ],
        ]);
```

the problem here is multiple : 
In the autocomplete field i obviously display the name (the end user search for the name, not the id) but this will be useless when i save since i need the user id.

So i start toying with the autocomplete js to display the name in a extra span, and replace the value of the autocomplete with the id. This is hacky and isn't usable because when i edit, i have the __toString() value from User displayed in the text field.

Comment: You can try a `one-to-many` relationship between `Registration` and `User`.

Comment: I have : Registration [1,1] - [0,n] User. Sorry, I don't see how your answer give a hint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to add a [`DataTransformer`](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/Form/DataTransformerInterface.html) at your field.

The whole documentation is available [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html).

**1. Create your `DataTransformer`**

This class will transform your username, which is a string, to a `User`.

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

// your User class :
use AppBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;

class  implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms an object (user) to a string (number).
     *
     * @param  User|null $user
     * @return string
     */
    public function transform($user)
    {
        if (null === $user) {
            return '';
        }

        return (string) $user;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a string (username) to an object (user).
     *
     * @param  string $username
     * @return User|null
     * @throws TransformationFailedException if object (user) is not found.
     */
    public function reverseTransform($username)
    {
        // no username ? It's optional, so that's ok
        if (!$issueNumber) {
            return;
        }

        $user = $this->em
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
            // query for the issue with this id
            ->findByUsername($username)
        ;

        if (null === $user) {
            // causes a validation error
            // this message is not shown to the user
            // see the invalid_message option
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                'User with username %s not found',
                $username
            ));
        }

        return $user;
    }
}
```

**2. Attach your datatransformer to your type**

You will have to get the EntityManager as argument, using services, or declare the UsernameToUserTransformer as a service with correct arguments

```
$builder
        ->add('user', EntityType::class, [
            'label' => 'user.name',
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'reguser',
            ],
            'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\User',
        ]);

$builder
     ->get('user')
     ->addModelTransformer(new UsernameToUserTransformer($this->em))
     ;
```

Comment: Thank you. It was indeed the way to go :)

Comment: I also added the feature of selection with autocomplete. The only problem i have is i can't use username, because some of them are computer generated, so the end user can't "guess" them. So, in the datatransformer, i used the format "lastname firstname : id", and revert it by exploding the string and find the User entity by id. So this is not 100% ideal : if a end user (secretary) wants to manually mess with the formatting the user won't be registered. But it's good anyhow.

Comment: @user29296 thanks for your comments. I am glad my answer could help.